# The reference to entity "f" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: android

I have the following xml file in my res/raw folder -

Title of RSS
        http://urlofthething.com

```
    <item>
        <title>Title</title>
        <description>The description goes here</description>
        <link>http://someurl.someurl.com/data/Content/1771370477</link>
        <guid>15626277</guid>
        <pubDate>28 Jan 2011 19:07:00 +0000</pubDate>
        <media:group>
            <media:content medium="video" duration="273"
                url="http://something.someurl.com/access/choice/u/0/1/15626277?rtspdirect=true&f=001110786488&stylesheet=mobile">

            </media:content>
        </media:group>
    </item>

    <item>
        <title>Title</title>
        <description>The description goes here</description>
        <link>http://someurl.someurl.com/data/Content/1771370477</link>
        <guid>15626277</guid>
        <pubDate>28 Jan 2011 19:07:00 +0000</pubDate>
        <media:group>
            <media:content medium="video" duration="273"
                url="http://something.someurl.com/access/choice/u/0/1/15626277?rtspdirect=true&f=001110786488&stylesheet=mobile">

            </media:content>
        </media:group>
    </item>
</channel>
```

and I am using

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxmlfile);
```

to read the file.

However on the line -

```
url="http://something.someurl.com/access/choice/u/0/1/15626277?rtspdirect=true&f=001110786488&stylesheet=mobile">
```

i am getting the following error -

```
The reference to entity "f" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The reference to entity "w" must end with the ';' delimiter exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-w-must-end-with-the-delimiter-exception)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since this is in XML, the parser expects the `&` symbol to precede entities such as `&quot;`.

Try replacing your `&` with `&amp;` and everything should be fine: this will be understood as being a real ampersand by the parser.

Comment: You are the guy!!
Thanks for help! :D

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `&amp;` instead of `&` in URL.