# Implementing Facepile app on blogger

Tags: blogger, facebook-social-plugins

I tried to implement the Facepile app on my blog. But it isn't working!

Codes used were:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY-APP-ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);`enter code here`
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="http://schooloffour.blogspot.in/" data-action="&lt;fb:facepile href=&quot;http://zhen.myfbse.com/rb-roastchicken.html&quot;  action=&quot;og_recipebox:planning_to_make&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; max_rows=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/fb:facepile&gt;" data-max-rows="1" data-width="300"></div>
```

Had added the facepile right after:`<data:post.body/>`

The error showing on the template code while saving it is :**Error parsing XML, line 634, column 62: The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter.**

How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The reference to entity "foo" must end with the ';' delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-foo-must-end-with-the-delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

The value of data-action property is wrong. Normal format of facepile is

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" data-action="video.watches" data-max-rows="1" data-width="300"></div>
```

Use this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/ to get a 100% running code. Fill url and action and click "Get Code" button. It makes codes in HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME or URL. Choose anyone you like.