# PrimeFaces Mobile reverse slide transition gives me ´The reference to entity "reverse" must end with the ';' delimiter.´

Tags: jsf, jquery-mobile, primefaces, xhtml

I would like to have a transition back of type `slide reversed` with this:

```
<p:button outcome="pm:first?transition=slide&reverse=true" value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-l" styleClass="ui-btn-left ui-btn-inline"/>
```

but I get this error:

```
20:47:09,976 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-38) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test-web/: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /views/index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 32] The reference to entity "reverse" must end with the ';' delimiter.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-w-must-end-with-the-delimiter-exception):
I simply replaced `&` with `&amp;` so I had to write it like this:

```
<p:button outcome="pm:first?transition=slide&amp;reverse=true" value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-l" styleClass="ui-btn-left ui-btn-inline"/>
```