# xsd validating url with parameters

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem when trying to validate a string. This string is supposed to be a URL, and so it can have parameters. When I add the "&" to add more than 1 parameter, I receive this error:

> Not well formed: The reference to entity "mysecondip" must end with
>   the ';' delimiter.

This is the xml:

```
<url>http://www.google.com?myip=192.168.0.1&mysecondip=192.168.0.2</url>
```

and the xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

[Sample](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=5fa608ad-43b1-4f3c-8396-915a6648d9e1-xsdvalidation#.VzRMU_mLT4Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found another question with same problem:

[The reference to entity "foo" must end with the ';' delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-foo-must-end-with-the-delimiter)

Thanks anyway, you can close this question or mark it as duplicate.