# The reference to entity "useLegacyDatetimecode" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: spring

It's one of those days where *nothing* works as it should.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mz_db?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimecode=false" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

The above giving me this error message:

> The reference to entity "useLegacyDatetimecode" must end with the ';' delimiter.

But the thing is that it is wrong:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]] »
[?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

es explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 105; The reference to entity "useLegacyDatetimecode" must end with the ';' delimiter.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
```

So what's this all about?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-foo-must-end-with-the-delimiter).  To embed an ampersand character in a url it needs to coded as `&amp;`

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mz_db?useSSL=false&amp;useLegacyDatetimecode=false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a minor error due to coding style.It worked for me for the latest version of Hibernate 5.4.12 .

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL;</property>
```