# getting error in rss feed when adding unsplash image

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, seo, rss, rss-reader

I am currently creating a RSS feed for my website and have included Unsplash images in my blog posts. However, when I attempted to add these images into the RSS feed,

But i got one error

**My Code**

```
 <media:thumbnail url="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642665076339-ca50c80a44e7?
ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80"
 width="220"/>
```

but i got error

**Error**

```
The reference to entity "ixid" must end with the ';' delimiter. xml(SemicolonRequiredInReference)
```

Please suggest why i am getting this error

Comment: Does [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483908/) resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand (`&`) is a special character in HTML and XML. If you want to use it as a normal character, you have to encode it correctly. Write `&amp;` instead of `&`:

```
 <media:thumbnail url="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642665076339-ca50c80a44e7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2070&amp;q=80"
 width="220"/>
```

The `&` (here) denotes the start of an encoded entity, such as `&lt;` for `<`, or `&amp;` for the ampersand itself. In your case, the parser tries to interpret `&w` as an entity but such entities are always terminated with a semicolon (`;`); thus, if that `;` is missing, you get the error message.